# How to change codec for voipstream in inet module

Tags: simulation, voip, omnet++, codec, inet

I’m interested in simulation voip traffic encoded with the opus codec. Since voipstream uses ffmpeg/libavcodec to run - I was hoping this would be as simple as changing the ini file to use a codec with the ID opus. When I do this I get the error at running the simulation “opus was not found in voipstreamsender”

I’ve had a look through the code in the module but can’t see anywhere the codecs are set up and so I just assumed they used the ids given in the avcodec.h file of libavcodec.

If anyone could advise on how to get this running I’d be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

The codec setup is [here](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/src/inet/applications/voipstream/VoipStreamSender.cc#L240), and it's using `avcodec_find_encoder_by_name()` so you must specify the **name** of the codec as the `codec` parameter. For opus, it should be `libopus` according to the ffmpeg docs.

Comment: Hi there I tried this however, while it now allows me to continue, in the results of the simulation with the degraded audio file - all I have is static. 
I have definitely included libopus and enabled it during the configuration and building of ffmpeg as I did not use an apt command to install it so Im not sure why this is happening.

I am running the Voipstream test program in OMNET++ and all of the default codecs produce resulting wav files that work as inteded